# Is it possible to use conftest.py fixtures from the another project?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm setting up Selenium & Appium framework for my automation tests. This framework will be installed as a package in other projects as I don't want to have all differents projects in one repository.

Is it possible to use conftest.py file that is kept in a framework in these separate projects? I've been looking across the web to find a solution, but couldn't find any solution.

Did anyone was able to make it work that way?

Comment: You can pass it as a plugin via `-p` argument, e.g. if the file is installed under `site-packages/myframework/conftest.py`, run `pytest -p myframework.conftest` to include it.

Comment: Thanks for that @hoefling. I'm trying it now, but it doesn't work. Do I need to add anything to setup.py in my framework too? Or should it work without it?

Comment: Sure, you have to treat it like a regular module in order to install it, best put it under some package you install already, e.g. `myframework.testing` etc so it is included automatically. The conftest in `myframework` then becomes a one-liner `pytest_plugins = ['myframework.testing']`. You can then include it the same way in other projects btw, forgot to mention it in the above comment.

Comment: Ok, it looks like I'm heading in the right direction, but it still does not work.

So, I have two projects: **framework** and **project1**.

In **framework** I have _testing_ module with conftest.py inside

In **framework** setup.py I include following code:
'entry_points={"pytest11": ["name_of_plugin = testing.conftest"]}'

Now in **project1** I run test with command line arg **-p testing.conftest**

I don't know if the above configuration is ok, but I get now **ValueError: Plugin already registered**

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Ah, I see you discovered the entry points ;-) This is indeed the best solution imaginable - you can now simply leave the `-p` option out. When starting `pytest`, it will scan the working set for entry points and load your plugin automatically, so there's no need to load it explicitly anymore.